# DataSnapshot.val() doesn't return processed value immediately

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

This is a method within a factory:

```
kbUser.getCurrentUserDetails = function(){
    return $rootScope.ref.child("user/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).once('value', function(snap){
        return snap.val();
    });
}
```

I call this method in a controller like this:

```
return kbUser.getCurrentUserDetails().then(function(details){

    // Here I need to do .val() once again
    for (var attrname in details.val()) { kbUser.userObject.details[attrname] = details.val()[attrname]; }
    kbUser.copyFirebaseDataToUser(firebaseUser).then(function(){
        return true;
    });
});
```

This is what I get returned: `details = W {A: P, W: U, g: ve}`, which doesn't correspond with my database.

When I read the `details` variable here, I have to do `details.val()` **again** to get the expected JSON object from my database. I don't get why the result of `snap.val()` isn't returned in the method, but just the 'raw' firebase datasnapshot `snap`. Does someone know why this occurs?

Assume that the factory is setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to use chain promise so that when `snap.val()` gets return you can get the data in it.

```
kbUser.getCurrentUserDetails().then(function(data){
  var user = data;
});
```

Comment: I'm actually doing that already. I added in my initial post the actual way I'm calling the function.